# SQL Server FOR/AFTER trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have an issue with an assignment. I believe I have the code all worked out properly but I keep getting a syntax error saying that the column "Total" Does not exist. I was under the impression that when you used "AS" it renamed the column that you are trying to use.

Here is my code any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
Use [IST278EagleCorp13-1]

Go

Alter Trigger DPInvOrderTrigger
On InventoryPart
For insert 
As
If exists ( Select Count(ReorderLevel * 4) ReorderLevel,Count(StockOnOrder +    StockLevel) AS Total 
 From InventoryPart
 Where Total > ReorderLevel)
Begin
    RaisError('Inventory to low. Transaction failed.',16,1)
    rollback tran
    End
```

These are the directions for this assignment.

```
/* Create a FOR|AFTER trigger named xxInvOrderTrigger for updates 
   to the InventoryPart table. If an update produces a record where 
   the (stockOnOrder + stockLevel) > (4 * reorderLevel) raise an 
   error (display an error) and rollback the change. */
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly** vendor-specific - so please update your tags to tell us what **database** (and which version) you're using (SQL is just the query language - not a database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding you are using `SQL Server` as your RDBMS and if I am not wrong in your below query `Total` is a column alias and you can't use `column alias` in `where` clause. That's why the error is for.

See a sample fiddle here for your understanding http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f902c/1

```
Select Count(ReorderLevel * 4) ReorderLevel,
Count(StockOnOrder +    StockLevel) AS Total
```

Rather you can do it using derived table like below

```
select ReorderLevel,
Total
from
(
Select Count(ReorderLevel * 4) ReorderLevel,
Count(StockOnOrder +    StockLevel) AS Total,
ReorderLevel 
 From InventoryPart
) tab
Where Total > ReorderLevel
```

Comment: Thank you for your help i think i have it figured out. as it turns out i didn't need the "count"'s either heh i do appreciate the help though thank you